# Prove that if $ \{(x, f(x))| x \in A \} $ is closed in $A \times F $, then $f$ is continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(E, d_{E}), (F, d_{F})$ be metric spaces ($d_{E}, d_{F}$ are distances in $E$ and $F$); $A \subset E, A \neq \emptyset $; $ f: A \rightarrow F $ is a map such that $\overline{f(A)}$ compact. Prove that if $ \{(x, f(x))| x \in A \} $ is closed in $A \times F $, then $f$ is continuous.
(Metric on $A \times F $ is $ d((a,b),(c,d)) = d_{E}(a,c)+d_{F}(b,d) $)

- **My solution so far:**
- I think am going to prove that for every closed set $V$ in $F$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed in $A$.

Comment: Use sequential definition of continuity.

Comment: Can you make it more clear?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ is not continous at some point $x_0\in A.$ From the compactness of $\overline{f(A)}$ there exists a sequence $x_n \to x_0 $ such that $f(x_n )\to y\neq f(x_0 ), y\in \overline{f(A)} .$ But then $(x_n , f(x_n ))\to (x_0 , y) $ and since the set $\{(x, f(x)  : x\in A\} $ is closed therefore $y=f(x_0)$ and we obtain a contradiction. So $f$ have to be a continous function.